# Trying to find channel by name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to find a channel named "raidprotect-logs" on my server, by name, with my bot. But, it throws me the error `ReferenceError: msg is not defined`. I put this code in `bot.on('ready', () => {`.

This is my code:

```
const logChannel = msg.client.channels.find('raidprotect-logs', channelName)
logChannel.send(logEmbed)
```

So, my main question is : How can I define `msg` ?

(I declared `logEmbed` properly before those lines)

I tried to put it in `bot.on('message', msg => {` section but it throws me the error `ReferenceError: channelName is not defined`. I think when I'll pass the `msg is not defined` error i'll have this one. I don't know how to define `channelName`.

Answer (score 1):

The message channel its a Discord collection, so you need use array map to find it.
You can get channel with 2 methods, second the better.

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    logChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'raidprotect-logs') // Find method 
    LogChannel = bot.channels.get('CHANNELID HERE') //Best way 
}
```

Comment: I have to put the code in `bot.on('ready', () => {`. So, how can I include `msg` to this section ? Because I have the `msg is not defined` error.

Comment: You can use this:

 `logChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'raidprotect-logs')` // Find method

  `logChannel = bot.channels.get('CHANNELID HERE')` //Best way

Comment: It will work only if I can define `msg` but I dont know how. How can I define it in `bot.on('ready'` ?

Comment: You cant define msg in `bot.on ready`. Because no fetch message in this statment. In this block you can use only only `bot.something`. Why you need use it only when bot ready? Why you need use `msg`  to get cahnnel?  In statment `bot on ready` you can use `bot` and get channel.

Comment: Yes but with the second method I can't find the channel by name, only by ID. In this case, I don't have the channel ID.

Comment: Also you can right click on the channel and get the channel ID, you neeed enable developer mode in Discord Settings for this. 
And fist method dont need the channel ID, so you can use it
`logChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'raidprotect-logs')`